# Eternal acceleration spacecraft because of carnivorous symbiotes - title of story

Tags: story-identification

There was a short story I'd like to find again, where an alien spacecraft visits Earth in the near future, but it's constantly accelerating.  The ship uses weird orbits such that its local acceleration gravity is kept the same, and it never stops.  The reason is that the aliens are symbiotic, and if the perceived gravity deviates, their symbiote panics and eats them.

Ring any bells?